# Project template type database model

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm currently planning an in-house data management tool to keep track of the progress of projects within my team, but am a bit stuck on how to model the database.

The physical representation is as follows:

There are locations (eg Shops) and each shop can have a number of projects associated with it at a given time. However each project follows a set number of tasks in a set order. For example a brand new shop might require stock to be ordered, staff to be hired etc., whereas a shop rebranding would have a different set of tasks.

What would be the best way to model this, so that I could create a new project for a shop, pick a certain project type and then track whether or not a task has been completed?

I would need this to be as flexible as possible, so that if a new task was to be required for a specific project type, this would be propagated to apply to all existing projects of this type.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a custom business application developer so I'm normally pretty easy to convince to build instead of buy.  However, for this particular application I'd think pretty hard about buying a project management tool instead of building.

There are lots of options available and they already have tons of flexibility and loads of reporting ready to go.  The downside of these tools is learning curve but I would guess that it would be *much* cheaper to buy in a case like this.

**EDIT: Additional info based on @OP's comment:**

If you have to build and you're main concern is that the template be reflected in each instance, then the key to the design is not in the schema design but in your data access design.  The trick is to relate each instance (of project, task, etc) to its template (project type, task type) and then to go after the data through the template and the instance at the same time.  Essentially you are using the template to give you the relational structure and outer joining to the instances for the actual details.  When you insert a new step into the template your outer join will be empty on the instance side, so your SQL needs to have COALESCE built into it if NULLs are going to give your UI code any grief.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joel. Unfortunately there isn't the scope to do this as the system needs to tie in with existing in-house systems. The problem is how to model the template type system in a database.